# rookie shopping cart won't add new items only replace 1st item when clicking add button

Tags: javascript, dom

instead of adding a new table row, the table row gets replaced

```
 itemRow = "<tr><td class='txt'>" + somevalue + "</td><td>" + somevalue + "</td><td>" + somevalue + "</td><td class='nr'>" + somevalue + "</td></tr>"

table = "<table>" + itemRow +"</table>"                         

div.innerHTML = table;
```

(note I cannot use jQuery or any other library for this assignment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to append the new row instead of replacing it. The question basically answers itself:

```
//In the beginning
var allRows = '';

//To add a new row
allRows += "the new row";
table = "<table>" + allRows + "<table>"
```

You might want to check some [DOM manipularion methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild) as well.